# Razor Pages get class Attributes in Unit Tests

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages

currently I'm trying to check if there is a way to get the class names of all attributes on razor page classes.
I unit tests all my controllers to look for an `AuthorizeFilter` so that it is impossible to forget it

Currently this is how I do it via MVC (does not work in Razor Pages):

```
var values = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
.ActionDescriptors
.Items
.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>()
.Select(a => new
{
    a.DisplayName,
    a.ControllerName,
    a.ActionName,
    AttributeRouteTemplate = a.AttributeRouteInfo?.Template,
    HttpMethods = string.Join(", ", a.ActionConstraints?.OfType<HttpMethodActionConstraint>().SingleOrDefault()?.HttpMethods ?? new string[] { "any" }),
    Parameters = a.Parameters?.Select(p => new
    {
        Type = p.ParameterType.Name,
        p.Name
    }),
    ControllerClassName = a.ControllerTypeInfo.FullName,
    ActionMethodName = a.MethodInfo.Name,
    Filters = a.FilterDescriptors?.Select(f => new
    {
        ClassName = f.Filter.GetType().FullName,
        f.Scope //10 = Global, 20 = Controller, 30 = Action
    }),
    Constraints = a.ActionConstraints?.Select(c => new
    {
        Type = c.GetType().Name
    }),
    RouteValues = a.RouteValues.Select(r => new
    {
        r.Key,
        r.Value
    }),
});
```

The problem is, that this code won't work with Razor Pages, i.e. `FilterDescriptors` is empty for `PageActionDescriptor`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`PageActionDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pageactiondescriptor) for `RazorPages` instead of `ControllerActionDescriptor`:

```
var values = actionDescriptorCollectionProvider
.ActionDescriptors
.Items
.OfType<PageActionDescriptor>()
.Select(descriptor => new
{
    // descriptor...,
    // ... 
});
```